# Scrap con BeautifulSoup pero no obtengo toda la info, los selectores son multiclase de un retail

Tags: python, scraping, beautifulsoup, selectores-css

Tengo que hacer un scrapin y estoy usando Jupyter, no puedo usar otra herramienta. NEcesito extraer datos como la marca, nombre, precios y en que posición se encuentra cada producto en la página. Los selectores css son multiclase en la página web.

Como este, en que necesito extraer el texto:
`<b class="jsx-1327784995 title1 secondary  jsx-3548557188 bold       pod-title title-rebrand">MIDEA</b>`

El problema que tengo es que no logro extraer todos los datos que busco, o bien obtengo solo una pequeña cantidad de datos o listas vacías.

NO estoy seguro si esto pasa porque los selectores tienen más de una clase, ya que cuando escribo todas las clases del selector que necesito
tal cual están en el HTML de la página solo obtengo una lista vacía. Mientras que cuando escribo solo la primera clase del selector solo obtengo los datos de 12 prodcutos de 48

Probé concatenando las clases con puntos como se hace en JavaScript pero no funcionó

Dejo mi código y en comentarios las ideas que probé y los resultados que obtuve.

Intenté cambiando el parser pero no vi cambios.

Soy nuevo en el desarrollo y tengo solo un poco de experiencia en scraping con bots en JS

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import urllib
import pandas as pd

baseurl = 'https://www.falabella.com/'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get('https://www.falabella.com/falabella-cl/category/cat3205/Refrigeradores')
soup = bs(r.content, parser='html.parser')


# neet to get this inner text
# <b class="jsx-1327784995 title1 secondary  jsx-3548557188 bold       pod-title title-rebrand">MIDEA</b>


# prod_list = soup.find_all('div', class_='jsx-1327784995 title1 secondary  jsx-3548557188 bold       pod-title title-rebrand')
# just gave me a empty list


# prod_list = soup.find_all('div', class_='jsx-3128226947')
#doesnt gather all the info


# prod_list = soup.find_all('div', class_='jsx-3128226947  layout_grid-view layout_view_4_GRID')
# just gave me a empty list


# prod_list = soup.find_all('div', class_='jsx-4001457643')
# doesnt get all data


prod_list = soup.select('#testId-pod-displaySubTitle-15693652')
# just gave me a empty list

print(prod_list)


# prod_links = []
# for x, item in enumerate(prod_list):
#     for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
#         print(x, link['href'])
# get just 12 out of 48 items
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Estás en el sitio en español, así que debo pedirte que vayas a [edit] y traduzcas tooooda la pregunta, incluyendo el título.

Comment: Hola y gracias Alfabro, es mi primera pregunta y no caché que estaba en la parte de español (Y)

Comment: Gracias por editar la pregunta. Mi siguiente pregunta es: has revisado su el contenido que quieres recuperar se carga dinámicamente con javascript? (Bs4 posiblemente no lo vería si es así)

Comment: @Alfabravo Lo que me llamó la atención es que si bien carga de forma dinámica igual podía extraer algunos datos. Cuando hice unos bots en java si la pág era dinámica no me extraía ningún dato. Tal como respondió Diego Medina, cambié el foco y decidí extraer los datos por medio de un json. Sin embargo ahora estoy leyendo documentación ya que no logro extraer precios

Comment: `
'prices': [
            {
              'label': '',
              'icons': 'cmr-icon',
              'symbol': '$ ',
              'type': 'cmrPrice',
              'crossed': False,
              'price': [
                '389.990'
              ]
            },
            {
              'label': '',
              'icons': '',
              'symbol': '$ ',
              'type': 'internetPrice',
              'crossed': False,
              'price': [
                '399.990'
              ]
            },
          ],
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me he topado con varias páginas como Saga Falabella al hacer scraping y hay algunas páginas que no te la data, la muestran dinámicamente con JS y es necesario analizar las solicitudes internas (no siempre es necesario selenium) y otras que "esconden" su data en algún script como Saga.

Si te vas al final del response que obtienes verás que ahí esta toda la data en un script con id = **NEXT_DATA**

Para obtener esta data usé este código:

```
url = 'https://www.falabella.com/falabella-cl/category/cat3205/Refrigeradores'
saga = requests.get(url)
s = BeautifulSoup(saga.text, 'lxml')
js_data = s.find('script', attrs={'id': '__NEXT_DATA__'})
js = json.loads(js_data.get_text())
```

Si imprimer "js" verás la data en un json.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Diego, estaba pensando en extraer el json y tu código me despejó varias dudas. Al no tener mucha exp con Python aun me falta rescatar el dato de precios pero estoy averiguando si lo puedo extraer de forma directa o debo extraer toda la info de del atributo 'prices' y empezar a cortar hasta obtener lo que necesito.
Saludos y reitero mis gracias!